# Two or more plulars in one string in android xml

Tags: android, xml, translation

I have to put in one xml string in android two plurals for age of user. And I have to handle sutch cases:

1. "You are 3 months old" (for parents which use child's profile)
2. "You are 1 year old"
3. "You are 1 year and 1 month old"
4. "You are 1 year and 3 months old"
5. "You are 2 years old"
6. "You are 3 years and 1 month old"
7. "You are 5 years and 3 months old"

And as you see only for english I need 6 diffrent cases. For another languages are more. Also I don't want to break string to two plurals beacuse in same languages order of world in sentence is diffrent.

Till now I alwas use plurals for only one quantity. In docs I don't see any hint how to correct solve sutch issue?

Actual solution:

in xml:

```
<string name="age_1">You are %1$s old</string>
<string name="age_2">You are %1$s and %2$s old</string>

<plurals name="age_months">
    <item quantity="one">%d month</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d months</item>
</plurals>

<plurals name="age_years">
    <item quantity="one">%d year</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d years</item>
</plurals>
```

And in code:

```
   if(years == 0) {
      String m = res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.age_months, months, months);
      ageTextView.setText(String.format(res.getString(R.age_1), m);
   } else if (months == 0){
      String y = res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.age_years, years, years);
      ageTextView.setText(String.format(res.getString(R.age_1), y);
    } else {
      String m = res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.age_months, months, months);
      String y = res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.age_years, years, years);
      ageTextView.setText(String.format(res.getString(R.age_2), y, m);

    }
```

But I'm looking for something which use one plural contant in xml:

```
   <plurals name="age_months">
        <item quantityA="one" quantityB="one">You are %1$d year %2$d month</item>
        <item quantityA="other"quantityB="one">You are %1$d years %2d month</item>
...
    </plurals>
```

Comment: You only need `year`, `years` and `month`, `months`. Two singulars and their corresponding plurals. So, what's the question all about?

Comment: @Rotwang in other langs order can be diffrent like "age are 3 monts and 2 years" and I don't want to split one sentence.

Comment: And what does it change? You always have to split the sentence. If you want things done properly.

Comment: I edit my queston. I put there my workaround (but maybe it's right solution). Alternatlivy I have to handle language in java code. :(

Comment: It seems to me you're on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that there is no bether solution than I used:

In xml:

```
<string name="age_1">You are %1$s old</string>
<string name="age_2">You are %1$s and %2$s old</string>

<plurals name="age_months">
    <item quantity="one">%d month</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d months</item>
</plurals>

<plurals name="age_years">
    <item quantity="one">%d year</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d years</item>
</plurals>
```

And some logic in code:

```
   if(years == 0) {
      String m = res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.age_months, months, months);
      ageTextView.setText(String.format(res.getString(R.age_1), m);
   } else if (months == 0){
      String y = res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.age_years, years, years);
      ageTextView.setText(String.format(res.getString(R.age_1), y);
    } else {
      String m = res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.age_months, months, months);
      String y = res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.age_years, years, years);
      ageTextView.setText(String.format(res.getString(R.age_2), y, m);

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this.

**Quantity Strings (Plurals)** :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#Plurals

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <plurals
        name="plural_name">
        <item
            quantity=["zero" | "one" | "two" | "few" | "many" | "other"]
            >text_string</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

Comment: This isn't helpful because it ignores the question. The submitter knows about plurals. They want to know how to use multiple quantities.